# codeigniter 3 Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

Tengo el siguiente problema repetido en varias secciones pero la resumiré, cabe destacar que esta en codeigniter3 con postgresql

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: controller/controlador_accion.php

Line Number: 515
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: controller/controlador_accion.php

Line Number: 517

controlador

```
 $cont=0;
    foreach ($PARAM_TRAMOS as $key => $value)
    {
        $PARAM_VALORES = $this->modelo_acciones->PARAM_VALORES($value['PARAM_TRAMOS_ID']);
        $PARAM_VALORES = $PARAM_VALORES['PARAM_VALORES'];
    
        if($value['TIPO']=='0')
        {
            if($cont==0){
                $D_M_C['ACCIONES_TIPO_0_TRAMO_A_MIN']=formatea_monto($value['MIN'],'NAME');$D_M_C['ACCIONES_TIPO_0_TRAMO_A_MAX']=formatea_monto($value['MAX'],'NAME');                    
                $D_M_C['ACCIONES_TIPO_0_TRAMO_A_COL_A_VALOR']=formatea_monto($PARAM_VALORES[0]['VALOR'],'NAME');$D_M_C['ACCIONES_TIPO_0_TRAMO_A_COL_A_SIGNIFICADO']=form_dropdown('ACCIONES_TIPO_0_TRAMO_A_COL_A_SIGNIFICADO', array('0' => '%', '1' => '$'), $PARAM_VALORES[0]['SIGNIFICADO'],'id="field-ACCIONES_TIPO_0_TRAMO_A_COL_A_SIGNIFICADO" style="width:50px;"');
                $D_M_C['ACCIONES_TIPO_0_TRAMO_A_COL_B_VALOR']=formatea_monto($PARAM_VALORES[1]['VALOR'],'NAME');$D_M_C['ACCIONES_TIPO_0_TRAMO_A_COL_B_SIGNIFICADO']=form_dropdown('ACCIONES_TIPO_0_TRAMO_A_COL_B_SIGNIFICADO', array('0' => '%', '1' => '$'), $PARAM_VALORES[1]['SIGNIFICADO'],'id="field-ACCIONES_TIPO_0_TRAMO_A_COL_B_SIGNIFICADO" style="width:50px;"');
                $cont++;continue;
            }
        }
     
        if($value['TIPO']=='1')
        {
            if($cont==0){
                $D_M_C['ACCIONES_TIPO_1_TRAMO_A_MIN']=formatea_monto($value['MIN'],'NAME');$D_M_C['ACCIONES_TIPO_1_TRAMO_A_MAX']=formatea_monto($value['MAX'],'NAME');                    
                $D_M_C['ACCIONES_TIPO_1_TRAMO_A_COL_A_VALOR']=formatea_monto($PARAM_VALORES[0]['VALOR'],'NAME');$D_M_C['ACCIONES_TIPO_1_TRAMO_A_COL_A_SIGNIFICADO']=form_dropdown('ACCIONES_TIPO_1_TRAMO_A_COL_A_SIGNIFICADO', array('0' => '%', '1' => '$'), $PARAM_VALORES[0]['SIGNIFICADO'],'id="field-ACCIONES_TIPO_1_TRAMO_A_COL_A_SIGNIFICADO" style="width:50px;"');
                $D_M_C['ACCIONES_TIPO_1_TRAMO_A_COL_B_VALOR']=formatea_monto($PARAM_VALORES[1]['VALOR'],'NAME');$D_M_C['ACCIONES_TIPO_1_TRAMO_A_COL_B_SIGNIFICADO']=form_dropdown('ACCIONES_TIPO_1_TRAMO_A_COL_B_SIGNIFICADO', array('0' => '%', '1' => '$'), $PARAM_VALORES[1]['SIGNIFICADO'],'id="field-ACCIONES_TIPO_1_TRAMO_A_COL_B_SIGNIFICADO" style="width:50px;"');
                $cont++;continue;
            }
           
        }
```

modelo

```
 public function PARAM_VALORES($PARAM_TRAMOS_ID)
 {
    $this->db->from('PARAM_VALORES');
    $this->db->where('PARAM_VALORES.PARAM_TRAMOS_ID',$PARAM_TRAMOS_ID);
    $db_resultado = $this->db->get()->result_array();

    if(count($db_resultado) > 0){
        $retorno = array(
            "cod"    => '0',
            "des"    => 'Exito',
            "PARAM_VALORES" => $db_resultado
        );  
    }else{
        $retorno = array(
            "cod"    => '1',
            "des"    => 'Error',
            "PARAM_VALORES" => array()
        );  
    }
    return $retorno;
}
```

Gracias por su tiempo y sus respuestas.

añado:
La linea 515 es un espacio en blanco justo antes de comenzar el if tipo == 1 y justo al acabar el if tipo == 0 .

La linea 517 es el corchete donde se abre el if tipo == 1

```
if($value['TIPO']=='1')
```

517       {

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea 517 del controlador?

Comment: La linea 515 es un espacio en blanco justo antes de comenzar el if tipo == 1 y justo al acabar el if tipo == 0 .

La linea 517 es el corchete donde se abre el if tipo == 1

            if($value['TIPO']=='1')
  517       {

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($valie);` y verifica el contenido y las claves, parece que ese objeto no es un array. Dinos qué muestra el `var_dump`

Comment: me arroja esto:
array(5) { ["PARAM_TRAMOS_ID"]=> string(3) "131" ["PARAM_META_ID"]=> string(2) "27" ["TIPO"]=> string(1) "0" ["MIN"]=> string(5) "0.000" ["MAX"]=> string(11) "9999999.000" } array(5) { ["PARAM_TRAMOS_ID"]=> string(3) "132" ["PARAM_META_ID"]=> string(2) "27" ["TIPO"]=> string(1) "0" ["MIN"]=> string(11) "9999999.000" ["MAX"]=> string(12) "10000000.000" } array(5) { ["PARAM_TRAMOS_ID"]=> string(3) "133" ["PARAM_META_ID"]=> string(2) "27" ["TIPO"]=> string(1) "0" ["MIN"]=> string(12) "10000000.000" ["MAX"]=> string(12) "99999999.000" }

Comment: Ahí no veo problema. Haz un `var_dump($PARAM_VALORES);`

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["PARAM_VALORES_ID"]=> string(3) "284" ["PARAM_TRAMOS_ID"]=> string(3) "149" ["ORDEN"]=> string(1) "1" ["VALOR"]=> string(10) "300000.000" ["SIGNIFICADO"]=> string(1) "1" } } array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { ["PARAM_VALORES_ID"]=> string(3) "251" ["PARAM_TRAMOS_ID"]=> string(3) "131" ["ORDEN"]=> string(1) "1" ["VALOR"]=> string(7) "100.000" ["SIGNIFICADO"]=> string(1) "0" } [1]=> array(5) { ["PARAM_VALORES_ID"]=> string(3) "252" ["PARAM_TRAMOS_ID"]=> string(3) "131" ["ORDEN"] no me dejo anotar todos los caracteres pero me arroja resultados, tampoco al parecer hay error

Comment: ¿Seguro que son esas líneas? Undefined offset ocurre cuando intentas acceder a un índice numérico que no existe.

Comment: Intenta poner los dos if así y dime si desaparece el error: `if($value[0]['TIPO']=='0')` y `if($value[0]['TIPO']=='1')`

Comment: en este caso me dice: undefined offset: 0 en la linea que va esto  if($value[0]['TIPO']=='0')

Comment: Ok revierte esos cambios sugeridos en el comentario anterior.

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($PARAM_TRAMOS);` y pulsa en [edit] para agregarlo a la pregunta. Si imprime un objeto grande con varios elementos pon un extracto del mismo, pero que se ve al menos un sub-elemento completo. Así podremos revisar el objeto completo con el que estás trabajando. Pon antes del `var_dump` algo como esto: `echo "<pre>";` para que el `var_dump` salga identado. Luego lo copias y lo pegas al final de la pregunta.